# component is a repeater and cannot be repainted via ajax directly

Tags: hibernate, wicket

I created List view which contain 2 textboxes
& i want to fill those on ajaxbutton submit.
but I am getting this error:

> Component com.cerebrum.pages.ShowCalculator$ShowCalculatorForm$2 has
>   been added to the   target. This component is a repeater and cannot be
>   repainted via ajax directly. Instead add   its parent or another
>   markup container higher in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should surround your list view with a WebMarkupContainer and add this markup container to the request target.

html code:

```
<div wicket:id="wmc">
    ...
    put your list view here
    ...
</div>
```

java code

```
final WebMarkupContainer wmc = new WebMarkupContainer("wmc");
add(wmc);
ListView yourListView = ...
// init your list view here
wmc.add(yourListView);

SubmitButton yourButton = new SubmitButton("yourButton") {
    @Override
    public void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        target.add(wmc);
    }
}
add(yourButton);
```

Comment: This solution is super. I had a wicket modal panel where it hosts dropdownchices and refreshing view. Using the onselectionchanged method of ddc makes the dialog to close and using the onAjaxBehavior makes the refreshing view unable to update. it just works nicely with the mvc. thanks