# Wicket: How to change contents of PageableListView dynamically?

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5

I have a html page with a search field and a table view displayed using `PageableListView`.

The data is present in `userListForTable` list. 
In the `onSubmit()` method of the `AjaxButton searchButton`, the`dbService.getEmployeeByName(searchInputString)` method returns a new list which I assign it to the `userListForTable` object.

While doing this, I assumed that when I assign a new list to `userListForTable`, the `PageableListView` table would be updated automatically but this is not happening.

Can anyone please help with it?

Efforts:

1. As mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668683/model-is-getting-updated-but-pageablelistview-not-reflecting-the-change-on-ui), I tried using `pageableListView.removeAll();` and setting `pageableListView.setReuseItems(true);`

Code:

```
pageableListView = new PageableListView<UserModel>("rows", new PropertyModel<List<UserModel>>(this, "userListForTable" ), 8) {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private ModalWindow modalWindow;

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<UserModel> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final UserModel userModel = (UserModel) arg0.getDefaultModelObject();
            arg0.add(new Label("name", userModel.getName()));
            arg0.add(new Label("gender", userModel.getGender()));
       }
}
```

The `searchButton`

```
AjaxButton searchButton = new AjaxButton("searchButton") {

        @Override
        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onSubmit();
            //get search string
            searchInputString = searchInput.getSearchString();
            //clear userListForTable and populate new List items
            userListForTable = null;
            userListForTable = dbService.getEmployeeByName(searchInputString);
            pageableListView.removeAll();
        }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you seem to forget adding  `pageableListView`  to `AjaxRequestTarget target` in order to refresh  your `PageableListView`.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Should I add it like, `target.addComponent(pageableListView);` ?

After making this change, when I click the search button, following error pops up, could you please help me with it?

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component com.mkyong.welcomepage.PageablePages$1 has been added to the target. This component is a repeater and cannot be repainted via ajax directly. Instead add its parent or another markup container higher in the hierarchy.
`

Comment: I thought by setting `pageableListView.setOutputMarkupId(true);` will solve the above error but it didn't

Comment: Component that have org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractRepeater as base class (like ListView, RepeatingView, etc…​) can not be directly updated via AJAX.

If we want to refresh their markup via AJAX we must add one of their parent  containers to the AjaxRequestTarget.

Comment: Thanks Andrea for the help. Along with your inputs and reference from this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663969/component-is-a-repeater-and-cannot-be-repainted-via-ajax-directly

I was able to repaint the pageableListView.